# Why cant I declare a generic list as nullable?

Tags: c#, null, nullable

Im trying to use the following code:

```
private Nullable<List<IpAddressRange>> ipAddressRangeToBind;
```

But I am getting the following warning:

> The type List must be a non-nullable value type in
>   order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Nullable'.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`List<T>` is already a reference type (for any kind of `T`) - you can only declare `Nullable<T>` where `T` is a non-nullable value type (it's declared as `Nullable<T> where T : struct`).

But that's okay, because if you just declare:

```
private List<IpAddressRange> ipAddressRangeToBind;
```

then you can still have

```
ipAddressRangeToBind = null;
```

because reference types are *always* nullable.

Answer (score 11):

`List<IpAddressRange>` is a reference type - it is already nullable - in fact it will be initialized to null by that declaration.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use it as is:

```
List<IpAddressRange> ipAddressRangeToBind = null;
```

List is already nullable.

Comment: true true, why cant I do it though out of interest...?

Comment: I guess because as The Jon Skeet explained, the of the constraint `Nullable<T> where T : struct` and `IpAddressRange` is not a `struct`. Why the constraint you ask? That's a different question :)

Comment: @Pete2k: I added an answer as to why don't the constraint exists.  It wasn't the first answer, so I don't want to claim credit for the answer, but it was too long to just put in a comment...

Answer (score 4):

Reference types cannot be wrapped in `Nullable<T>` due to a `where T : struct` constraint on the generic.

The reasons for this constraint are:

1. Reference types are already nullable by definition, and
2. Nullable is not very space efficient, but more a "logical" nullability.

`Nullable<T>` has a bool property `HasValue` and a type `T` property `Value` which contains the actual value-type value.

Even if `HasValue == false` (that is, if the nullable wrapped variable is set to `null`), you STILL consume the space for the value type as if it was there.

It's *logically* nullable to allow you to specify *optional* behavior, but it doesn't save any space.  This is very similar to how boost::optional works in C++.

Comment: I see now what the Where clause is now!

Comment: A lot of annoyances with `Nullable<T>` stem from a desire to have it pretend that an empty instance is `null`.  An unfortunate decision, IMHO, since it prevents methods like `TryGetValue`, which may or may not have a `T` to return, from simply returning a `TValue?` without having to worry about the type of `TValue` (if the `HasValue` of the returned item is false, the key does not exist; if `HasValue` is true, the key exists even if the stored `Value` happens to be `null`).  On the other hand, while nullable types should logically be covariant with their type parameter...

Comment: ...(since any `Animal?` should be able to hold the contents of any `Cat?`), making covariance work while having a cast from `Animal?` or `Animal??` to `Object` preserve the degree of nullability, would require that conversion from a nullable type to `Object` not use normal boxing.  Under normal boxing rules, boxed value types are *always* mutable (even if the underlying value type is supposedly "immutable").  Too bad, since such a design increases the difficulty of making things like a "readable dictionary" interface covariant with regard to types of values stored therein.